# Is part of the bump function “ultraconvex”?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f$ be the usual bump function: $f(x)= \exp \frac{1}{x^2-1}$ for $-1<x<1$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

I’m wondering if there exists an interval starting at $x=-1$ over which $f$ is “ultraconvex”, i.e. derivatives of all orders are nonnegative. (I took the term “ultraconvex” from the first solution for [Putnam 2018 A5](https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2018s.pdf), which inspired this line of thinking).

I suspect that this is not the case, and my approach would be to prove that:

for every $\delta > 0,$ there exist constants $x_0 \in (-1,-1+\delta)$ and $k \geq 1$ such that $f^{(k)}(x_0)<0$.

From the mean value theorem and induction, I see that there exists a strictly deceasing sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subset (-1,0]$ such that $f^{(n)}(x_n)=0$, but I don’t know how to prove that this sequence converges to -1, if indeed it is possible to prove.

Thank you

Comment: Wait, but doesn't the said Putnam solution prove just that - I mean, that an ultraconvex function which is 0 _anywhere_ is consequently 0 _everywhere_?